# Research on formalization of what constitutes a good theorem

Tags: soft-question, formalization

This question is about automating theorem proving. Now automated theorem proving, as currently understood in CS literature, has little to do with pure mathematics as practiced on this site (I believe the former tends to be about statements of low level of abstraction such as some theorems of Euclidean geometry; the question is not about such statements).

So let me clarify what I mean by automating theorem proving: this means (a) to be able to formalize the proofs of deep results in pure mathematics (e.g. V. Lafforgue's results on Langlands) (b) to have a machine that is capable of producing "interesting" results of equal/higher depth on a consistent basis. The progress on (a) tends to be by current or former pure mathematicians (e.g. Kevin Buzzard) which, I believe, makes this question appropriate to MO.

Of course, if you have sufficient computational power, you can just try all possible ways to adjoin axioms and syllogisms, and you would produce a lot of theorems. If you are persistent enough, you will produce some number of interesting theorems but the percentage they would make up would be vanishingly small, I believe. Therefore, to do (b) you need your machine to know what is an "interesting" theorem.

Different people tend to find different things interesting but I believe that if you fix a particular area of mathematics, there do exist theorems which 90% of mathematicians working in this area find interesting, so the set of "interesting theorems" is not empty. The question is: how do we formally define it? Are there any papers on this subject? If not, maybe some people who have tried hard to do this could share their insights?

One concern I have is that if you tried to explain what humans mean by "interesting" to a machine, it might look pretty arbitrary (and reflect certain pieces of intuition hard-coded into our brains by nature/evolution). As one homotopy theorist [puts it](https://thetech.com/2018/11/01/importance-theoretical-research): "studying something like mathematics is essentially understanding the way the human mind thinks." Maybe that homotopy theorist is right (i.e. you could learn something about an alien civilization just by looking at the pure math section of their arXiv).

I do not know but for some reason, whenever I look at the definition of etale fundamental group, I feel like it was always a part of the primate geometric intuition, it just takes some time to write it out explicitly. But let us see what research says about this.

Comment: When computers will do this, we will be all left without jobs. So this research should not be encouraged:-)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I realize your comment is probably not completely serious, but from my own perspective, I definitely want this to happen as soon as possible because then there will be more beautiful mathematics. I realize that other people may value economic benefits provided by the current situtation more, everyone has their reasons.

Comment: My personal intuition is that the best way to explain to a machine what we mean by an interesting theorem is *not* to define that concept formally, but to convert as much existing mathematics as possible to machine-readable form, and let a neural net figure out for itself what "interesting" means by finding its own patterns in the data.

Comment: @TimothyChow yes, that also sounds reasonable. I am very ignorant about those networks. I think there is some amount of data you have to feed to it before it figures anything out (and by human standards, this amount of data can be pretty large). Any estimates on that (though I do not really know what is a good unit of information in mathematics)?

Comment: @schematic_boi: "there will be more beautiful mathematics"... but there will be no people able to appreciate it. Even nowadays there is more beautiful mathematics around than people are able or willing to read.

Comment: @schematic_boy: look at what happened to chess and checkers after computers defeated the world champions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I am not sure what point you are making about chess. Are you claiming that chess is in decline? The statistics I've seen about chess participation worldwide and the amount of money in chess suggest the opposite.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: I am curious to look at this statistics. Especially its dynamics in the last 40 years or so. My own experience shows substantial decline, but it is based only on my perception, I am not aware about statistics.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard maybe you could share your thoughts?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko it is not necessarily true that there is more beautiful mathematics around than people are able or willing to read. I mean, it is true in the sense of the sheer amount but if we look at the depth of the existing plots (say, number-theoretic Langlands, geometric Langlands, HMS, etc.) that is a bounded number, so to speak. And I think it is possible to understand more-or-less everything that is known about the deepest existing plot in mathematics. Machine such as proposed in the question should be able to quickly produce much deeper plots so there may be observable difference.

Comment: @schematic_boi: I disagree. What constitutes the "deepest existing plot" is a matter of current fashion. There is a lot of deep work of the past and present which is little read if read at all,  because it does not fit the current fashion. Sometimes fashion changes and it resurfaces, sometimes 100 later. I have encountered many examples during my career.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I disagree. The phrase "deepest existing plot", in my opinion, refered to any given plot into which the largest amount of effort has been invested. Granted, fashion in mathematics is not something intrinsically mathematical, but it still led people to invest a lot of effort into the fashionable plots so it does not matter right now for what reason that effort has been invested, only that it has been invested. My reason for thinking so is that the OP was interested in reading beatiful mathematics, and to read beautiful mathematics you need papers that were actually written...

Comment: ...not papers that could have been hypothetically produced had the fashion gone in another direction (or that will be produced eventually when the fashion goes in the other direction).